# How to update a value from a field without refreshing the page Odoo

Tags: odoo-14

I'm creating a new sector on the settings page of my module, where I have a value and an update icon, which aims to update the field value when I click on the icon.

But when I call the function to execute the function, the page is reloaded and I never get the value, but the value is printed in the terminal with a logger, does anyone have any suggestions?

**My XML code:**

```
<button type="object" name="refresh_credits" class="btn-link" icon="fa-refresh"/>
<span class="btn-link">Credits</span>
<field name="new_credits"/>
```

**My python code inside a class:**

```
class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    new_credits = fields.Integer()

    def refresh_credits(self):
        data_details_credits = self.env['show.credits'].content_credits_info()
        _logger.info(self.env['show.credits'].content_credits_info()[4])
        self.new_credits = data_details_credits[4]
```

Comment: try adding `return {'type': 'ir.actions.client', 'tag': 'reload'}` at the end of your function

[free addon](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/web_ir_actions_act_view_reload)

Comment: Didn't work, continues to refresh the page without updating the value with the return

Comment: I mean the value is being updated in the terminal but never being shown in the front end  because of the page refresh

Comment: I've been doing some tests and I think the problem is in the XML in the button when I say type="object", but I can't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override set_values and get_values method to update the values in settings. We cannot directly update the values in general settings.

Below is the example:

```
def set_values(self):
    super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
    self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('MODULE_NAME.new_credits',
                                                     self.new_credits)
    

@api.model
def get_values(self):
    res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
    config = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
    config_key = config.get_param('MODULE_NAME.new_credits')
    if config_zoom_key:
        res.update(
            field_name=config_key
        )

    return res
```

And also for better understanding, watch this video:

[Add fields general settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsVoYPQ4-J4)

Comment: I thought that it was not a good practice to store the values in the system parameters, but I will do it that way, thank you